# How do I instantiate this 'class with generic parameter' in run-time

Tags: c#

Consider following line of code :

```
classA<classB> C;
```

I want to create instance of C during run-time by using System.Reflection instead. For that I will need to know Type of classA and classB during run-time.

I know how to get type of **classB**

```
Type classBType = AssemblyContaingClassB.GetType("namespace.classB");
```

Q1> How can I use this **classBType** to get type of **classA** ?

Q2> I understand that to create instance in run-time, we call following line of code:

```
object C = Activator.CreateInstance(TypeName);
```

To create instance of **C**, What TypeName should above code use? will Type of classA sufficient to create this instance

Thanks in advance and Apology if this question is too basic. I am new to c#.

**EDIT:**

The problem is Fixed. From p.s.w.g's answer, there was problem in getting type of class with generic parameter. The solution on how to get type of generic parameter can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589613/c-sharp-how-do-i-gettype-of-class-with-generic-parameter-in-run-time). After that I just did what p.s.w.g's answer suggest and its work.

Comment: In C# the concept is called [*generics*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564.aspx), not "templates".

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect duplicate suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @JonathonReinhart . I have changed title from template to generic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your latest update it seems like the issue is loading the type `classA<>` at run-time. To avoid naming conflicts the C# compiler generates a name like `` SimpleClassName`N `` where `N` is the number of generic type parameters, so to get the `classA<>` type through reflection, use the name `` namespace.classA`1 ``. After that, you would simply use the [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method:

```
var classAType = AssemblyContaingClassA.GetType("namespace.classA`1");
var classBType = AssemblyContaingClassB.GetType("namespace.classB");
var genericType = classAType.MakeGenericType(classBType);

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Of course, unless you *have* to load the types at run-time, it's easier and safer to get the types at compile-time using the [`typeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) operator:

```
var classAType = typeof(classA<>);
var classBType = typeof(classB);
var genericType = classAType.MakeGenericType(classBType);

object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(genericType);
```

Comment: it strikes me that, if you're in a position where you could write the second form of your code, you could just as easily have `new classA<classB>();` and be done with it - or is there some circumstance that I'm not thinking of here?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever It could be the case that you have to write them separately. e.g. `Type MethodA() { return typeof(classA<>); }`, `Type MethodB() { return typeof(classB); }`, and `Type MethodC() { return MethodA().MakeGenericType(MethodB()); }`

Comment: I got value of classAType = null. Do you know how can i fix this?

Comment: It throw exception with message "Could not load type 'classA' from assembly '//assembly details//'"

Comment: I suggest that you edit the question on getting type of classAType : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17589613/how-do-i-gettype-of-class-with-generic-parameter-in-run-time/17589713?noredirect=1#17589941
Then i can accept this post as accepted answer.

Comment: @someone_smiley You're right, the compiler munges generic class names a little bit. I've updated my answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 8):

You could use the [`MakeGenericType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx) method on the open-generic `classA<>` type:

```
Type classBType = ... get from somewhere at runtime
Type classAType = typeof(classA<>).MakeGenericType(classBType);
object classAInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(classAType);
```

The `MakeGenericType` will close the `classA<>` generic and make it possible to instantiate.

Comment: The assembly containing definition of classA will be loaded at runtime. So i think i can't use "Typeof(classA<>)". Am i wrong?

Comment: No, you are absolutely right. You will have to load the `classAType` using reflection in this case.