# C# - How do I GetType of 'class with generic parameter' in run-time?

Tags: c#

I have a generic class as shown below:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyClass<T> : MyAnotherClass
    {
        public MyClass();
        public MyClass(T obj);
        public T Object { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I don't understand why following line of code return null (`throwing exception with message :  "Could not load type 'MyClass' from assembly '//assembly details//' "`)

```
Type MyClassType = AssemblyContaingMyClass.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass");
```

Is it illegal to use **Assembly.GetType(className)** with generic class?

Can you suggest any alternate method to get type of generic class in run-time?

Thanks in advance and Apology if this question is too basic. I am new to c#.

**EDIT :**

Forgot to mention. the assembly containing MyClass will be loaded run-time.

Comment: Try out `MyNameSpace.MyClass<>`

Comment: I did. also tried MyNameSpace.MyClass<T>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you have to use CLR naming to access generic types at runtime:

```
AssemblyContaingMyClass.GetType("MyNameSpace.MyClass`1");
```

In the CLR, generics are named without mentioning type parameters, but with a backtick(`` ` ``) followed by the number of generic type parameters.

Comment: +1. And it's not that hard to check, full name of the type (from the same assembly) can be extracted by `typeof(MyNameSpace.MyClass<>).FullName`. As far as I remember, other assemblies have full names in line of `AssemblyName+NameSpace.ClassName\`3` (for 3 generic parameters)

Comment: +1. Its work like magic!!! Thank you very much :) btw, in debugger it says my class name is " MyClass`1 ". Is this normal or there is error in it?

Comment: @someone_smiley - yes, that's normal.

Comment: Wish i could upvote more that once, thank you @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 7):

The reason you cannot do this is because, simply put, there is no class named `MyClass`. There's the Generic Class Definition which name is something like `` MyClass`1 ``, and then there's every variant of the types which name looks like `` MyClass`1[System.String] `` etc.

The easiest way to get the type is using the `typeof` keyword like so:

```
var genericType = typeof(MyClass<>);
var specificType = typeof(MyClass<string>);
```

However if you must load it from an assembly by its name, you need to provide the full name like so:

```
var genericType = assembly.GetType("MyClass`1");
var specificType = assembly.GetType("MyClass`1[System.String]");
```

When it comes to the naming of the generic types it's `` ClassName`<number of generic arguments> ``

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are after?

```
    public class MyClass<T>
    {
        public T TheGeneric { get; set; }
    }


    Type theType = typeof(MyClass<>);
```

Answer (score 0):

try(without T):

```
Type template = typeof(MyNameSpace.MyClass<>);
```

Comment: I can't: The assembly containing my class will be loaded at run-time.